# Why won't my api route return anything when testing on Postman?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

how come when I try to return something in the `logout()` function inside my `api.php` file (`return "testing";`, for example) I get a blank message in Postman?

Here's some [high level context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238226/how-would-i-create-the-logout-method-based-on-my-already-created-and-working-log) (my previous SO question) of what I'm trying to achieve.  Before trying to achieve this - I need to make sure the API route's working by trying to return something simple.  I'm not sure why it's not working.  Thanks in advance for any input :).

[image: Postman Header Screenshot]

Here's api.php:

```
 Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
   Route::post('/logout', [RegisterController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

Line 65 in `index.php`:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Here's what's appearing in Postman

```
"message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php",
    "line": 43,
    "trace": [
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/CompiledRouteCollection.php",
        "line": 144,
        "function": "handleMatchedRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 647,
        "function": "match",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\CompiledRouteCollection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 636,
        "function": "findRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 625,
        "function": "dispatchToRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 166,
        "function": "dispatch",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 128,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
        "line": 31,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
        "line": 40,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
        "line": 27,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
        "line": 86,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
        "line": 57,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php",
        "line": 52,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 103,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 141,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 110,
        "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/myProject/public/index.php",
        "line": 65,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: How do you call it in postman?

Comment: Please [edit] your question o show us the code from around line 65 in `/home/vagrant/myProject/public/index.php`. The stuff postman got back from your api is a php trace back from an exception mentioned right at the t.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc I'm calling it like this `http://myProject.test/api/logout`

Comment: @O.Jones I've edited my question to include line 65 in `index.php` and its surroundings

Comment: Please Share api.php

Comment: @MoolchandSharma I've posted `api.php` in my original post.  I've tried placing the `logout` post route outside of the middleware but I'm still getting the same result - just for your infomation.

Comment: Okay, Please Share Your Postman Header Screenshot

Comment: @MoolchandSharma I've shared my postman header screenshot in my original post

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's interested:  I had to run `php artisan route:cache`.  That seemed to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You may run this command to clear the route cache.

```
php artisan route:clear
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching